# why dotnet core 3.1 route is case sensitive?

Tags: .net-core, routes, case-sensitive

I'm writing a blazor web assembly app using dotnetcore 3.1.
I create a Web api controller  and force route like this

```
[Route("api/structures")]
[ApiController]
public class StructuresController : ControllerBase
```

but when i use the following URL, i get nothing

> https://localhost:44351/api/structures

but it works for :

> https://localhost:44351/api/Structures

i don't understand why?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming it’s because of the ordering of the [ApiController] annotation. If you put the api controller annotation above route then it will then check the [Route] annotation after it checks for the [ApiController] annotation.

```
[ApiController]
[Route(“api/structures”)]
```